# Text to Json conversion in node.js

Tags: npm

When I am trying to convert plain text data to JSON using Node.js, I am getting the following error:

```
Duplicate data found. Make sure, in objects, no duplicate properties exist;in arrays, no duplicate values.
```

How to overcome this issue ? If we want to convert plain text to Json while having duplicate values, is it possible?

Comment: What method are you using to convert?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A description of what you are doing doesn't give a clear enough picture of the problem. You need to provide a [mcve]. You could provide it in the form of a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please take more care with your choice of tags. [tag:npm] doesn't seem relevent. Possibly [tag:node.js], [tag:javascript], and [tag:json] would be.